# Are roasted bean flours edible as is?

Tags: lentils

By bean flour, I mean dry beans that have been made into a flour-like consistency such as through using a high-powered blender. From a digestion standpoint, it seems at this stage to be equivalent to raw beans, but would roasting the flour in the oven or on the stovetop allow it to be digested without problem?

Comment: I doubt it. Carbs and proteins need hydration to cook. Roasting does not supply that for dry beans.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not. Lectins (the toxins found in raw beans) are inactivated by boiling, but dry heat seems to be less effective (though not entirely ineffective). See https://www.peanutscience.com/doi/pdf/10.3146/i0095-3679-13-1-2 .

Comment: They're only an issue in some beans though. Off the top of my head red lentils and chickpeas should both be ok. Perhaps the OP would like to clarify what they're planning on using, especially given "beans" in the title and "lentils" in the tags. Yes there's overlap in those categories, but some crops are clearly one or the other